# Database search with multi joins

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a MySQL database and I want to perform a little bigger search.
I have about 10k records in one of the tables and It's expected to grow, but slowly.
The biggest problem is that to perform the search I have to make a query with 4 JOINS which I think causes the search to be slow.
So here is some example struct:

```
[table records]
id INT unsigned PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
description text
label INT unsigned
type INT unsigned
price DECIMAL

[table records_labels]
id INT unsigned PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
label varchar

[table records_types]
id INT unsigned PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
type varchar

[table records_serial]
id INT unsigned PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
serial varchar
record INT unsigned

[table records_barcode]
id INT unsigned PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
barcode varchar
record INT unsigned
```

So here is how the things run:
I run a query which selects `records.id, records.description, records.price, records_labels.label, records_types.type, records_serial.serial, records_barcode.barcode;`
So the full query is like this:

```
SELECT records.id, records.description, records.price, records_labels.label, records_types.type, records_serial.serial, records_barcode.barcode FROM records JOIN records_labels ON records_labels.id = records.label JOIN records_types ON records_types.id = records.type LEFT JOIN records_serial ON records_serial.record = record.id LEFT JOIN records_barcode ON records_barcode.record = record.id WHERE records_serial.serial LIKE %SEARCH_TERM% OR records_barcode.barcode LIKE %SEARCH_TERM%
```

I think that the solution here is indexing I guess, but I'm not very familiar with it.
So shortly, how to speed up and optimize query of this kind?

Comment: Paul, where is this "record INT unsigned", on the tables records_serial and records_barcode,  connected with? In your query you have "records_serial.record = record.id" and I'm not sure where this table record is coming from. Is this query working?

Comment: record_serial and record_barcode's record column is matched to records.id column. Actually this here is just an example, but my original query is similar and working, but slow (20-30 seconds to execute and return a result).

Comment: I think @medina meant that you have a couple of typos in your query.

Comment: It is Possible, I'm sorry. I'm stucked on this for about 2 hours and my head is burning.

Comment: I think the query is slow because of the `%SEARCH_TERM%` conditions, which, btw, cannot be index optimized. Have you tried the query without them?

Comment: try also `EXPLAIN <your query>` at the console to get a run down of how the query is processed. What do you get?

Comment: Here is the explain on the query http://pastebin.com/CiS9t9kx .
Executing without search (where condition) is fast as hell, but this is the idea of the query to search by barcodes or serials and to return a result.

Comment: Hey Paul, If you could put here the real query would be much easier to help you out.. Is it possible? ;-)

Comment: @medina there isn't any difference. :) I saw that I've typed something wrong and just edited it. The idea is to show query's struct. Everything works, but the execution time is inaceptable 9 seconds for this query is a lot of time. :(

Comment: what storage engine you use? MyISAM can use full text indexes.

Comment: I've been always using MyISAM, but this time I used InnoDB.
I'm still in development state, so it is not a problem to switch to MyISAM, but will this help? I'm still thinking that I'm doing something wrong. Maybe my database design is bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### indexing records  (OPTIONAL, BUT RECOMENDED)

```
CREATE INDEX ilabel ON records (`label`);
CREATE INDEX itype ON records (`type`);
```

#### fixing records_label

```
ALTER TABLE records_label MODIFY label INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL;
CREATE INDEX ilabel ON records_label (`label`);
```

#### fixing records_types

```
ALTER TABLE records_types MODIFY `type` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL;
CREATE INDEX itype ON records_types (`type`);
```

#### the search

```
SELECT r.id, r.description, r.price, rl.label, 
    rt.`type`, records_serial.`serial`, records_barcode.barcode 
FROM records r
INNER JOIN records_labels rl ON rl.id = r.label 
INNER JOIN records_types rt ON rt.id = r.`type` 
WHERE 
    r.id IN (
        SELECT rs.record
        FROM records_serial rs
        WHERE rs.`serial` LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' 
    )
    OR 
    r.id IN (
        SELECT rb.record
        FROM records_barcode rb
        WHERE rb.barcode LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%'
    );
```

#### There is no much what I can do for your where clause. the Like %% kills any sort of performance if you keen to change it for something like this LIKE 'SEARCH_TERM%', then you could create the index below

```
CREATE INDEX iserial ON records_serial (`serial`(10));
CREATE INDEX ibarcode ON records_barcode (`barcode`(10));
```

It could be improved even more but with theses changes I believe you achieve what you are looking for. ;-)

Comment: Thank you! The indexing does its job :)